# MSP430 relocation types missing in documentation

Tags: c, microcontroller, elf, msp430, relocation

If you check the [slaa534.pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa534/slaa534.pdf#page=70&zoom=auto,0,701.3) file from Texas Instruments there are only 18 relocation types:

`Idx. Name.
 1. R_MSP430_NONE
 2. R_MSP430_ABS32
 3. R_MSP430_ABS16
 4. R_MSP430_ABS8
 5. R_MSP430_PCR16
 6. R_MSP430X_PCR20_EXT_SRC
 7. R_MSP430X_PCR20_EXT_DST
 8. R_MSP430X_PCR20_EXT_ODST
 9. R_MSP430X_ABS20_EXT_SRC
10. R_MSP430X_ABS20_EXT_DST
11. R_MSP430X_ABS20_EXT_ODST
12. R_MSP430X_ABS20_ADR_SRC
13. R_MSP430X_ABS20_ADR_DST
14. R_MSP430X_PCR16
15. R_MSP430X_PCR20_CALL
16. R_MSP430X_ABS16
17. R_MSP430_ABS_HI16
18. R_MSP430_PREL31`

However, I got a ELF file that has more. I checked on the internet and found an interesting file from *binutils* package called [*elf32-msp430.c*](http://fossies.org/linux/gdb/bfd/elf32-msp430.c).

It looks like a software piece to perform the relocation of data, and it has these relocation types.

`1. BFD_RELOC_NONE
 2. BFD_RELOC_32
 3. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_10_PCREL
 4. BFD_RELOC_16
 5. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_16_PCREL
 6. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_16
 7. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_16_PCREL_BYTE
 8. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_16_BYTE
 9. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_2X_PCREL
10. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_RL_PCREL
11. BFD_RELOC_8
12. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_SYM_DIFF
13. BFD_RELOC_32
14. BFD_RELOC_16
15. BFD_RELOC_8
16. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_ABS8
17. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_PCR20_EXT_SRC
18. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_PCR20_EXT_DST
19. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_PCR20_EXT_ODST
20. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_ABS20_EXT_SRC
21. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_ABS20_EXT_DST
22. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_ABS20_EXT_ODST
23. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_ABS20_ADR_SRC
24. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_ABS20_ADR_DST
25. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_PCR16
26. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_PCR20_CALL
27. BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_ABS16
28. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_ABS_HI16
29. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_PREL31
30. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_10_PCREL
31. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_2X_PCREL
32. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_RL_PCREL
33. BFD_RELOC_MSP430_SYM_DIFF`

Where can I seek the information to perform these relocations ?

Thank you.

Comment: [Here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bfd-2.9.1/html_mono/bfd.html#SEC79), for example...

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's the Binary File Descriptor Library manual. There is no information about these relocation types. It's general information. I was looking for a table like in the first link with all the attributes of each type.

Comment: The first list is hardware specific. The second is library specific. If you look closely at the c file you provided, you will notice it is mapping one into the other.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But doesn't matter what I search for, neither *BFD_RELOC_MSP430X_PCR16* or *R_MSP430X_PCR16* none of them appear on it. So I don't have the info to perform the relocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using another compiler. Those relocations (second ones) are from MSPGCC ando not from TI compiler. I will just search for the documentation of the MSPGCC instead.